# Testing for players within a specified rectangular area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up a pvp arena and need a command block to test for players within a specified set of coordinates. I need to take a rectangular area so please don't reply with `/testfor @p[x=,y=,z=,r=]`

I saw one thing about using [x,y,z,dx,dy,dz] but I couldn't get it to work, and as I've never used the (dx,dy,dz) before, I don't know if I input them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The delta parameters (`dx`, `dy`, `dz`) state the number of blocks from the origin (`x`, `y`, `z`) to the opposite corner of the rectangular area, rather than a second set of coordinates.

For example, the following looks for players with the first corner at (100, 64, 100) to the opposite corner at (105, 70, 105):

```
/testfor @a[100,64,100,dx=5,dy=6,dz=5]
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if entity @a[x=100,y=64,z=100,dz=6,dy=6,dz=5] run <chained command>`