# Minecraft give effect when stand on a certain block in a 10 by 10 range

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a base that that when someone enters it they get glowing so that I can see them.

I don't want the effect to be permanent and the effect should be given only when being on that block. If that player steps away from a 10x10 area around the block they should then no longer have the glowing effect. Is there a command to do something of the sort?

Comment: What have you tried already? We can't help you until you show us everything you've tried up to this point.

Comment: Perhaps this previous post can help you out [How to teleport players when they enter a certain area/coordinates?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210849/how-to-teleport-players-when-they-enter-a-certain-area-coordinates/210889#210889) for player position detection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing for players within a specified rectangular area](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245506/testing-for-players-within-a-specified-rectangular-area)

Comment: I've edited your question to more specifically describe what I think you want to achieve to prevent closure. If it wasn't what you meant and the suggested duplicate doesn't answer your question, please edit it to be more specific or give a reason why it shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score -1):

You could set up pressure plates and dispensers, and fill the dispensers with splash potions of glow if that is a thing. I don't really play Minecraft much.